# Inicialização App Phonegap TitleBar

Tags: apache-cordova, app-hibrido

Porque o quando faço buid do meu app e executo ele no meu celular aparece na inicialização do mesmo um barrinha cinza com o nome da aplicação e o fundo preto? Alguem sabe como tirar isto?

Comment: Você definiu um splash screen ? é difícil dizer oque pode ser sem imagem ou código, poste algo para esclarecer mais está dúvida.

Comment: Cara eu não define nenhuma splash screen será que é isto? É só na inicialização, então descarta fullscreen=false

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução e sei que muitos irão ficar felizes por essa solução.
Adicione essa linha abaixo dentro da tag widget do `config.xml`:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

E agora adicione o código abaixo em seu `config.xml`:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">

       <supports-screens 
              android:xlargeScreens="false" 
              android:largeScreens="false" 
              android:smallScreens="false" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ></activity>
        </application>
</gap:config-file>
```